# How do I sort a txt file dataset into two datasets using a label?

Tags: python, numpy

I loaded the data set with

```
np.loadtxt("dataset")
```

which has given me an array of arrays? I guess what I am trying to do is sort these internal arrays which comprise of three variables x, y and z where z is either a +1 or a -1 which denotes if it is positive or negative.

what I am trying to do is to break down these arrays into two separate arrays for processing so I can plot the negative labeled arrays against the positive ones.

example dataset

```
[[ 1 2 1 ],

[ 2 1 -1 ],

[ 3 2 1 ]]
```

this is what I've thought of so far

```
negex = []
posex = []

if dataset[2] < 0
   negex.append()
else
   posex.append()
```

I know this is wrong but it is the best I can think of. The reason why I put dataset[2] is because I'm addressing the third variable of the array and basically I'm saying if less than 0 which is negative one is then append to negex if not less than 0 then append to posex

ultimately I want to transform this dataset to the point where I can plug it into matplotlib and get points also I'm only allowed to use numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can break down the dataset into two separate arrays as following:

```
negex, posex = np.delete(dataset[dataset[:,2] < 0],2,1)  , np.delete(dataset[dataset[:,2] > 0],2,1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what did you think of my original solution how good was it? was I onto something or was I just flat wrong?

Comment: I think there are some mistakes in your solution, I assume that your dataset is an array of arrays ( or a 2d array), then now dataset[2] doesn't represent the third variable, actually dataset[2] =  [ 3 2 1 ]. So it depends on how you represent your dataset. and note that the append method cannot be empty, you should pass something into it.